# SQL JOIN, or two selects?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I'm using a MYSQL database.

I have the following:

```
tbl1

ID(p) | FID(p)
1     7
2     7
2     8
7     2
3     9

tbl2

DATA(p) | ID(f)
AAA      7
BBB      7
CCC      8
```

I need to select ALL FID where ID = 2 from tbl1   (7, 8)
I then need to select all DATA where ID = the results of the first query (returning AAA, BBB, CCC)

Can this be done in one query, or two? If you can point me in the direction of the right operator I can work it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT b.DATA 
FROM tbl1 a
LEFT JOIN tbl2 b ON b.ID = a.FID
WHERE a.ID = 2
```

Will return:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Comment: So will `select DATA from tbl2`

Comment: @xception You should submit that as an answer.

Comment: It's obviously not what he's looking for, I just am in the mood of stating the obvious, I voted your answer, I just thought it funny.

Comment: Thanks, I needed a RIGHT JOIN though instead.

Comment: You're joining and then filtering to a certain a.ID; consider filtering before: `... FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE ID=2) a LEFT JOIN ...`

Answer (score 2):

The right operator is `JOIN`.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not perfectly clear on what needs to be joined but something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl2 INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE ID=2) a ON a.FID=tbl2.ID
```

Comment: I don't think there is a need for sub-queries here. This may be slightly more costly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "INNER JOIN" to select multiple fields from multiple tables.

```
SELECT T1.FID, T2.DATA
FROM tbl1 T1 
WHERE T1.ID = 2
INNER JOIN tbl2 T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```